# Flutter StatefulWidget

Tags: flutter, dart

Looking at the StatefulWidget usage, I am wondering about the design decision to have circular dependency like this:

```dart
class YellowBird extends StatefulWidget {
  const YellowBird({ Key key }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _YellowBirdState createState() => _YellowBirdState();
}

class _YellowBirdState extends State<YellowBird> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(color: const Color(0xFFFFE306));
  }
}
```

example is taken from [Flutter StatefulWidget docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StatefulWidget-class.html#widgets.StatefulWidget.1)

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

This is (one of the) correct way's to build a stateful widget and is properly in line with the flutter documentation.

Comment: I'm looking for the reason for this design

Answer (score 0):

This is not a [circular dependency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_dependency). You are defining a Stateful Widget class, and a corresponding State class. 
The Widget contains a State object (or rather a sub-class of it), using the principle of [composition-over-inheritance](https://flutter.dev/docs/resources/technical-overview#composition--inheritance).

From the [Stateful widget documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StatefulWidget-class.html):

> StatefulWidget instances themselves are immutable and store their mutable state either in separate State objects that are created by the createState method, or in objects to which that State subscribes, for example Stream or ChangeNotifier objects, to which references are stored in final fields on the StatefulWidget itself.

This way Flutter framework can better manage the manipulation and change of this Widget's data. For example (from the link above):

> [...] multiple State objects might be associated with the same StatefulWidget if that widget has been inserted into the tree in multiple places.

This principle of composition-over-inheritance is a core-concept of Flutter framework and most IDE's can create this boilerplate code for you automatically (e.g. typing `stful` on AndroidStudio suggests the StatefulWidgets class and its State related class) so you don't have to worry about it.

Comment: I don't think you understood this properly.